# Layout changes when exporting in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, layouts

When I export to PDF or SVG, the layout changes and doesn't look the same as in QGIS. How do I get it right when exporting?

How it looks in qgis and how it should be:

[image]

When exporting to PDF:

[image]

And SVG:
[image]

Comment: I guess you are using a diagonal hashed filling?

Comment: It is perfectly possible to export diagonal hashed fillings, but they will look like your 2nd picture all the time.

Answer (score 6):

Hashed fillings for simple polygon symbologies tend to behave undesirable when exporting images. This is - at least I think - due to the fact that they are based on dots per inch.

Anyway, there is a workaround. Have a look at the following (German) screenshot:

[image]

First, use the green plus at the top right of your layers symbology dialogue (first red box) to add a new layer to your symbology.

Secondly, change your symbology layer type from a simple one to a linear filling using the dropdown menu below (second red box).

Thirdly, adjust the linear filling to your liking (roation, line width, colour, space between lines).

Last but not least, for your original symbology, change the filling from "diagonal hashed" to "none".

The second symbology layer is necessary, since linear filling has no border. Now the exported images should be more to your liking.

Comment: Feel free to upvote any helpful answers and accept the one which helped you most - this way others users with similar issues may find their solution quicker @PeterAndresen

Answer (score 1):

Do you export at 100dpi? Or higher? If you export at 300dpi your textures will 3x smaller.

Comment: Please refrain from adding comments/questions for clarifications as answers - instead add a comment.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to expand on your statement and gives steps to solve the problem.